# How do get the info of cucumber tag mentioned in Test Runner class in Glue class?

Tags: cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I need to get the info about the tags mentioned in Test Runner in Glue class ?
Is it possible?
Like for example 
In Test Runner
tags = {“@LoginTest”}

Want this info in Glue code

Answer (score 0):

Yes my friend it is possible to retrieve the details related to Tags. Could you please tell me whether you are trying to retrieve this information during runtime or after the completion of the cucumber test scripts execution.

Comment: During Runtime.